# Breezejs non scalar complex type not updating properly when refetched from server

Tags: breeze, complextype

We are running into an issue with updating non scalar complex type.

Our simplified metadata looks like this

## Table

```
shortName: 'Table',
defaultResourceName: "/table",
dataProperties: {
    name: { max: 50, required: true },
    description: { max: 500},
    columns: {complexType: 'Column', isScalar: false}
    ...
}
```

## Column

```
shortName: 'Column',
isComplexType: true,
dataProperties: {
    name: { max: 50, required: true },
    description: { max: 500 },
    ...
}
```

Our backend is document based nosqldb.

In the UI, we display all the tables and its columns in a tree like structure. User can click on a Table name or column and edit it's properties in a property editor. Table and Column have separate editors, even though internally they are part of the same object.

Initially when we display the tree we only fetch limited no. of dataproperties of the json, only the ones that are required to be displayed in the tree. But when the user clicks on a particular table or a column we fetch the entire table (columns are complex types) from the server and update the cache to display them in the editor.

We are using knockout as the model library so all the properties are knockout observables. We are passing the same breeze entity objects to viewmodels of these editors as well as the tree.

If the user clicks on a table in the tree, and edits name or description in the editor, we are seeing table name in the tree is also changing as it should, since they are both the same observable. But when I click on a column name in the tree, and edit the column name in the editor, I do not see the change getting reflected in the tree.

What I think is happening here is, when I am re-querying the same object from the server to display in the editor, table name which a simple property is being updated with the new value from the server, but column name which is part of complex object, is actually getting replaced with new values from server, since each complex object in the array itself is being replaced. So it seems like tree and editor has different obsrevables.

Funny thing is, if after clicking on a particular column and having it displayed in the editor, I move to a different module (we are using spa), and then come back to the original module again, then if I click on the same column again and update the name, this time the change is getting reflected in the tree. But not the first time.

Could this be a bug, or am I missing something? Is there a workaround?

We are using breeze js 1.5.6
Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure the complex types in your observable array are in fact observable? Observable arrays != arrays of observables. The fact that something works when you open it the second time sounds like you have some race condition going on with binding.

Comment: Thank you very much for looking into this. Yes, the complex type in the observable array are themselves observable.

Comment: Actually in breeze.debug.js (ver 1.5.6, line 8167) if I comment out the line below , I see even the column changes are reflected in the tree, even though I see all the columns are duplicated as expected. That tells me, the individual complex object are not updated but replaced with new one. So the observable in the tree is different from the observable object in the editor. Sounds like a bug to me :)
if  (!__arrayEquals(oldVal, newVal, coEquals)) {

 // clear the old array and push new objects into it.
 
 //oldVal.length = 0;
 
 newVal.forEach(function (nv) {
 oldVal.push(nv);
});
}